# I am trying to get the value of the property in my dropdown menu in react

Tags: reactjs, return-value, controlled-component

I am trying to `console.log` the value of the dropdown item that I selected. I have tried `e.target.value` and `data.value`. `e.target.value` returns nothing and `data.value` returns `undefined`.

```
<DropdownItem
    onClick={(e, data) => {
        // this.setState({ choice: this.props.size });

        // value.addChoices(this.state.choice);
        console.log(data.value);
    }}
    className="bg-info"
>
    {this.props.size}
</DropdownItem>
```

Comment: Which library are you using? Cause `DropdownItem` isn't a HTML standard tag.
And normally you wouldn't have a `data.value` as part of a click event.

Comment: I’m using reactrtrap should I switch to a normal select menu?

Comment: And I found dAta.value on another thread tried it and got undefined .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do normally is to pass a value prop (that's why e.target.value is undefined, because you did not pass any value).

i.e.:

```
        <DropdownMenu>
          <DropdownItem value='one' onClick={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)}>Foo Action One</DropdownItem>
        </DropdownMenu>
```

Full example code (changing the reactstrap sample component):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Dropdown, DropdownToggle, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem } from 'reactstrap';

export default class DropdownTest extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      dropdownOpen: false
    };
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      dropdownOpen: !prevState.dropdownOpen
    }));
  }

  handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggle}>
        <DropdownToggle caret>
          Dropdown
        </DropdownToggle>
        <DropdownMenu>
          <DropdownItem value='one' onClick={this.handleClick}>Foo Action One</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem value='two' onClick={this.handleClick}>Bar Action Two</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem value='three' onClick={this.handleClick}>Quo Action Three</DropdownItem>
        </DropdownMenu>
      </Dropdown>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this will give you the text value inside of the `DropdownItem` button

```
<DropdownItem
  onClick={e => {
    // this.setState({ choice: this.props.size });

    // value.addChoices(this.state.choice);
    console.log(e.target.innerText);
  }}
  className="bg-info"
>
  {this.props.size}
</DropdownItem>
```